# Button not responding to click

Tags: javascript, onclick

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="song" placeholder="Enter a Song">
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <ul id="songList"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = buttonHandler;
};

function buttonHandler(){
    var input = document.getElementById("song");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li = input.innerHTML;
    var ul = document.getElementById("songList");
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

The above code can be found here also http://jsbin.com/IyaNOPa/1/edit

Why when I enter a song name in and click the button does it not add the name to the list? I've made something like this a few times and it worked, now I tried it in a different way and I'm not sure what my error is.

Comment: "Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. 
buttonHandler" referencing "ul.appendChild(li);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
 li = input.innerHTML;
```

to

```
 li.innerHTML = input.value;
```

- You are overwriting `li` to empty string since innerHTML of input will return you that.
- You need to set the innerHTML of li with the value propery of the input.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/UbInuTIY/1/)

Comment: ah thank you and now that i have that right is there a way to chain this piece of code   `var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = input;`

Comment: @user3131132 Yes you are right. If this helped you and you dont get any other better answer do you mind accepting the answer. I see that you have asked question and have not accepted answer in any of them where i guess some of them you had got an answer.

Comment: nope no problem i will when it allows me to, but when i try ` var li = document.createElement("li").innerHTML=input;` it does not work properly. http://jsbin.com/IyaNOPa/1/edit

Comment: @user3131132 No you cannot chain it that way for obvious reasons. Because you need to first create the element and then set its innerHTML.

Comment: @user3131132 You can't chain it that way. You can do `document.createElement("li").innerHTML=document.getElementById("song").value` but then you won't be able to reference the newly created `li` node while appending it to your `ul#songlist`. With jQuery you might have done `$('<li>').html($('#song').val()).appendTo('#songlist')`